# What will HashMap(it) do?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, kotlin

I'm learning the sample code about 《Kotlin for android developers》 at https://github.com/antoniolg/Kotlin-for-Android-Developers

In the code  `.parseList { DayForecast(HashMap(it)) }`, I can't understand what the function HashMap(it) will do. Is HashMap() a class and accept a parmater `it`?

And more, I think that the full code of class `DayForecast(...)..` is Code A, right?

Again, If I create a object `var myDayForecast=DayForecast(10L,"Desciption",10,5,"http://www.a.com",10L)`, will myDayForecast.map be empty, right?

**Code A**

```
class DayForecast(var map: MutableMap<String, Any?>) {
    var _id: Long by map
    var date: Long by map
    var description: String by map
    var high: Int by map
    var low: Int by map
    var iconUrl: String by map
    var cityId: Long by map

    constructor(date: Long, description: String, high: Int, low: Int, iconUrl: String, cityId: Long)
            : this(map: MutableMap<String, Any?>=HashMap()) {
        this.date = date
        this.description = description
        this.high = high
        this.low = low
        this.iconUrl = iconUrl
        this.cityId = cityId
    }
}
```

**Original Code**

```
override fun requestForecastByZipCode(zipCode: Long, date: Long) = forecastDbHelper.use {

        val dailyRequest = "${DayForecastTable.CITY_ID} = ? AND ${DayForecastTable.DATE} >= ?"
        val dailyForecast = select(DayForecastTable.NAME)
                .whereSimple(dailyRequest, zipCode.toString(), date.toString())
                .parseList { DayForecast(HashMap(it)) }

        val city = select(CityForecastTable.NAME)
                .whereSimple("${CityForecastTable.ID} = ?", zipCode.toString())
                .parseOpt { CityForecast(HashMap(it), dailyForecast) }

        city?.let { dataMapper.convertToDomain(it) }
}


class DayForecast(var map: MutableMap<String, Any?>) {
    var _id: Long by map
    var date: Long by map
    var description: String by map
    var high: Int by map
    var low: Int by map
    var iconUrl: String by map
    var cityId: Long by map

    constructor(date: Long, description: String, high: Int, low: Int, iconUrl: String, cityId: Long)
            : this(HashMap()) {
        this.date = date
        this.description = description
        this.high = high
        this.low = low
        this.iconUrl = iconUrl
        this.cityId = cityId
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think from the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47066705/what-happened-when-the-code-hashmapit-is-run/47112857#47112857) , you should already understand that parseList provides the closure `{ DayForecast(HashMap(it)) }` with a [`Map`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/index.html) object.

But as you now show the definition of `DayForecast`

`class DayForecast(var map: MutableMap<String, Any?>)`

requires a [`MutableMap`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-map/index.html)

The primary difference between a `MutableMap` and a `Map` is that a `Map` cannot be changed,  while a `MutableMap` can be changed.

The reason `DayForecast` needs a `MutableMap` is because in the secondary constructor the object passed in, referred to as `map` is altered (mutated).  This is part of you other recent [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47175802/why-isnt-mydayforecast-map-empty/47176792#47176792).

[HashMap](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-hash-map/index.html) is a Hash table based implementation of the `MutableMap` interface, so it can be used were ever a `MutableMap` is expected.

So to summarize:

DayForecast() expects a `MutableMap` object to be passed to it's primary constructor, but parseList only provides a `Map` to the closure it receives, so the solution is to insert the `HashMap()` to create a `MutableMap`.

This should also answer a question you posed in a comment, why can't parseList just take the closure `{ DayForecast(it) }` instead of `{ DayForecast(HashMap(it)) }` ?  It's because as you show above the constructor for DayForecast() expects a `MutableMap`,  which `it` is not (it is a `Map`) while `HashMap(it)` is a `MutableMap`.

Answer (score 2):

> I can't understand what the function `HashMap(it)` will do. Is `HashMap()` a class and accept a parameter `it`?

From the [docs of `HashMap(Map)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#HashMap-java.util.Map-):

> Constructs a new `HashMap` with the same mappings as the specified `Map`. The `HashMap` is created with default load factor (0.75) and an initial capacity sufficient to hold the mappings in the specified `Map`.

To answer your question: yes, `HashMap` is a class, which accepts parameter `it` which need to be an instance of `Map`.