# Why isn't myDayForecast.map empty?

Tags: android, kotlin

I create a object myDayForecast with secondary construction, I think the var bb will be empty because the parmater of secondary construction which pass to main construction is HashMap().
I see some document about HashMap(), it will return empty.

But after I run the code, I find the var bb isn't empty (You can see image), why?

```
var myDayForecast= DayForecast(15L,"Desciption",10,5,"http://www.a.com",10L)
var bb=myDayForecast.map

class DayForecast(var map: MutableMap<String, Any?>) {
    var _id: Long by map
    var date: Long by map
    var description: String by map
    var high: Int by map
    var low: Int by map
    var iconUrl: String by map
    var cityId: Long by map

    constructor(date: Long, description: String, high: Int, low: Int, iconUrl: String, cityId: Long)
            : this(HashMap()) {
        this.date = date
        this.description = description
        this.high = high
        this.low = low
        this.iconUrl = iconUrl
        this.cityId = cityId
    }
}
```

**Result Image**

[image]

Comment: why did you tag this as Java?

Comment: If the book you are reading doesn't already have answers to most of your last questions, it doesn't work as an introduction to Kotlin and you should read another one (and then get back to this example if you want). I suspect that if you read the previous sections more carefully, you'll find that it explains it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In at the end if the secondary constructor definition line:

```
constructor(date: Long, description: String, high: Int, low: Int, iconUrl: String, cityId: Long)
            : this(HashMap()) {
```

`: this(HashMap())` is a call to the primary constructor:

```
DayForecast(var map: MutableMap<String, Any?>)
```

but with an empty HashMap as the argument.

So when you make the call :

```
var myDayForecast=DayForecast(15L,"Desciption",10,5,"http://www.a.com",10L)
```

one of the first things that happens is that the primary constructor is called with the empty HashMap as noted above.

This is as if you called the primary constructor like this:

DayForcast(map = HashMap())

So now map has been set to an empty HashMap.

In the secondary constructor,  each of the fields are marked with `by` `map`, where `map` is a MutableMap property of DayForecast. as seen here:

```
class DayForecast(var map: MutableMap<String, Any?>) {
    var _id: Long by map
    var date: Long by map
    var description: String by map
    var high: Int by map
    var low: Int by map
    var iconUrl: String by map
    var cityId: Long by map 
    ...
}
```

This means that any access to those fields is delegated to the object referred to by `map`, which in this case is a `MutableMap` object.  For a MutableMap object this means that the compiler will translate calls such as `this.date = 15L` into something like this this.map.put("date", 15L) and references like `blah = this.date` will be translated into something like,  `blah = this.map.get("date")`

Next, after the primary constructor has been called, the second part of the secondary constructor is run.

```
    this.date = date
    this.description = description
    this.high = high
    this.low = low
    this.iconUrl = iconUrl
    this.cityId = cityId
```

Now since each of these properties are declared as `var propXYZ by map`
each of these calls are translated into calls like `this.map.put("date", date)`, which will fill in the initially empty HashMap with values, so that by the time you call

`var bb=myDayForecast.map` , map is now a filled in HashMap.

Please take a look at the [delegate-properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html) section of the Kotlin documentation, if this is still confusing.

Comment: Thanks! What I can't understand is why  "this.date = date"  is equal to  "this.map.date = date"

Comment: it's due to the "var date: Long by map"  request to data are forwarded to the map object.  read the delegate-properties link I included above for more info

Comment: specifically the "by map" being the key part,  ie date is accessed via the object referred to by the map property

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean that both this.date and map[""] point to the same address ?

Comment: I updated my answer with more info on how this works but, no this.date and map[""] are not the same address.  The compiler recognizes that you marked the field data (and the others) as being provided *by* the delegate object referred to by map,  and compiles the code such that this.date = 15L,  really calls something like this.map.put("date", 15L), ie it *delegates* the date property to the map field of type MuteableMap

Comment: Thank you! Do you mean that the system do the operation this.map.put("date", 15L) automatically when I do this.date = 15L ?
And the system do the operation this.date = 80L automatically when I do this.map.put("date", 80L) ?

Comment: yes to this.date => this.map.put("date", 15L), as that is the "real" operation and this.date is just a short cut.  so no to this.map.put("date", 15L) being changed to this.date = 15L,  as this.map.put("date", 15L) is the real operation.  Hopefully this answers your question, any thing more and we should do it in chat

Answer (score 3):

You're using a [map to store your property data](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#storing-properties-in-a-map) in it. This is done via `by map` and works for getting and setting. By assigning a value to the properties you add elements to the map. So initially your `HashMap` is empty, but at the end of the constructor, you've added values to it implicitly. *Kotlin* doesn't create another field or mechanism to store the values otherwise.